# BigQuery Java : query response truncated

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I have currently a problem with the java BQ api. I wrapped it in Clojure and the results are too short compared to what they have to be.

When I execute the query in the web browser, the query returns more than 230 000 rows.
In java/Clojure however, the job succeeds but the output consists in 100 000 rows.

It is strange because if I remember well, it worked with the same code before. And when it did not work, at least the job failed. Here the result is truncated.
I put setMaxResult to 1 000 000 000 so I do not think it is the problem.

Is there sometimes a problem with Google itself ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `maxResults` limit, responses are also limited to 10 MB. By default, there is no maximum row count, and only the byte limit applies.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query

There are other limits also: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries

You will need to use pagination, and never relly on an API to return all data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I programmed so a query function with both Java and Clojure that uses pagination and it works very well !